# An interesting first order method

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the problem of minimizing $f(x)+g(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$, both are smooth, and the following first order method:
$$
x_{k+1}= \operatorname{argmin}_x\left \{  \nabla f(x_k)^T(x-x_k) + \frac{1}{\alpha^{p-1} p} \|x-(x_k - \alpha \nabla g(x_k))\|_p^p \right \}
$$

Is it a special case of some known method?

What about the stochastic setting, when $f(x) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m f_i(x)$, replacing $\nabla f$ by $\nabla f_i$, where $i$ is chosen at random?

Note that it is easy to see that for $p=2$, we obtain exactly the (stochastic) gradient method with step-size $\alpha$.

The method was coded by mistake, instead of a more natural method which we aimed to test,
$$
x_{k+1}= \operatorname{argmin}_x \left\{ [\nabla f(x_k) + \nabla g(x_k)]^T(x-x_k) + \frac{1}{\alpha^{p-1} p} \|x-x_k\|_p^p \right \}
$$
with $p=3$. The stochastic version of the  'mistake' turned out to perform much better than the stochastic version of the more natural method above.

Comment: Do you have examples of specific pairs of functions $f$ and $g$ on which the 'mistake' performed better than the original method? Did the 'mistake' also outperform the method $x_{k+1}=x_k-\alpha\nabla f(x_k)-\alpha\nabla g(x_k)$ on any of these pairs of functions?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson $f$ is an average of functions of the form $\log(\exp(p(x))+1)$ where $p$ is a 3rd degree multivariate polynomial, and $g$ is the squared Eurclidean norm. The regular gradient descent you asked about performs poorly, and we thought that changing the approximating model from quadratic to cubic would improve the performance. It indeed did so. As I pointed out, the regular gradient method corresponds to the quadratic model.

Comment: I can't make the link but this might be related to $\alpha$-divergences minimization, you may take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence#Instances_of_f-divergences but on this field, google scholar will help more then google.

Comment: It looks like a modified proximal gradient method where the proximal is defined with respect to a different norm; similar to what @P.Quinton mentioned, it must be related to [Bregman divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence).

Comment: What is weird is that the distance is not from $x_k$.

Comment: @AlexShtof Seems similar to Alternating Linearization Method, and other generalized proximal gradient methods with $L_p$ norm. This method is close to being a proper 'predictor-corrector' method. Currently, you are 'predicting' by minimizing a quadratic approximation of g, via $y_k = x_k -\alpha \nabla g(x_k)$ .Then ideally you should correct by using the gradient of $\nabla f(y_k)$ in the minimization of the quadratic approximation of $f$, instead of using the gradient $\nabla f(x_k)$.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis is right, this looks rather similar to a Bregman prox (also called a D-resolvent). The modern paper for Bregman theory (in preprint form) is here https://pcombet.math.ncsu.edu/sicon2.pdf ... among other things, they show that although a divergence is not a true norm, there are analogous properties required for iterative convergence analysis -- this paper shows Bregman generalizations of firm nonexpansiveness, monotonicity, and many more notions